# What is the purpose of the any() and all() methods in Laravel?

Tags: laravel-8

In the code below, you can see that the `$errors` variable has two functions: `any()` and `all()`. How do they work? What does `$errors->any()` and `$errors->all()` do?

```
@if($errors->any())
    @foreach ($errors->all() as $element)
        <li>{{ $element }}</li>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

any() is bool method that return false if no error is retrieve. And all() retrieve an array of messages for all fields.